# get several image data about several different images with canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I want to draw some images in the canvas and get the data of them using for loop...
I put the image object in the array and also the data should be in the array too.
Here is the code.

What should I do if I want to get the array of several images data?

```
window.onload = function(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
  imgObj[i]= new Image();
  imgObj[i].onload = function()
  {
   context.drawImage(imgObj[i], 0, 0);
   var imagedata1 = context.getImageData(0,0,742, 274);
   data[i] = imagedata1.data;
  };
  imgObj[i].src = "/img"+i+".bmp";
 }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

"The getImageData() method returns an ImageData object that copies the pixel data for the specified rectangle on a canvas.

Tip: The ImageData object is not a picture, it specifies a part (rectangle) on the canvas, and holds information of every pixel inside that rectangle." (source: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/canvas_getimagedata.asp)

Therefore try adding the images to the canvas one by one and retrieve the image data rectangle  corresponding to the image's position and size every time;

http://s11.postimage.org/aszz0oxc3/canvas.png

In step 2 you retrieve the imagedata for the green image and for step 3 you retrieve the image data for the blue image and you do this even though you still have your green image under.

Therefore this is what you need to replace:

```
imagedata[i] = context.getImageData(image[i].x,image[i].y,image[i].width, image[i].height);
```

This needs to be done after each image added on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

u should have to add the listener in canvas:

```
function eventShipLoaded() {

            ctx.drawImage(img, 50, 50, 118,100);    //draw image in canvas  

            ctx.drawImage(img, 487, 180, 118,100);      
        }
window.addEventListener('load', eventShipLoaded , false);
var img = new Image();
        img.addEventListener('load', eventShipLoaded , false);
        img.src = "pic.jpg";
```